# Randomly subset or sample images in a folder

Tags: r, image, random, rstudio, image-classification

I am trying to teach myself image classification in R (keras package) using the Cats and Dogs dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/data

But the dataset is quite large, and I would like to work with a smaller number of images to begin - around 2000-3000, mainly for speed as I have an older computer.

Is there any way that I can subset a list of files in a folder (i.e. the images) straight from RStudio and copy/move these to a new folder? Doing this manually would be a nightmare for 20,000 images!

Ideally I would like to subset in a random fashion, but failing that, I imagine sampling sequentially (e.g. in order of file name) would probably not affect my results that much.

Comment: Get the files in the folder, `all_fls <- list.files(pattern = "\\.jpg")` (or other file extension) and then `fls <- sample(all_fls, 2000)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use R in Kaggle, so you don't really need to train on your own hardware or download your local copy of the dataset. To extract a balanced sample of cats and dogs from the training archive in Kaggle, you could go with something like this:

```
fs::dir_tree("../input")
# ../input
# └── dogs-vs-cats
#     ├── sampleSubmission.csv
#     ├── test1.zip
#     └── train.zip

# list archive content as data.frame
train_ls <- unzip("../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip", list = TRUE)
str(train_ls)
# 'data.frame': 25001 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Name  : chr  "train/" "train/cat.0.jpg" "train/cat.1.jpg" "train/cat.10.jpg" ...
#  $ Length: num  0 12414 16880 34315 28377 ...
#  $ Date  : POSIXct, format: "2013-09-20 10:12:00" "2013-09-20 10:05:00" ...

cats <- grep("cat", train_ls$Name, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
dogs <- grep("dog", train_ls$Name, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# a balanced dataset, equal number of occurances:
str(cats); str(dogs)
# chr [1:12500] "train/cat.0.jpg" "train/cat.1.jpg" "train/cat.10.jpg" ...
# chr [1:12500] "train/dog.0.jpg" "train/dog.1.jpg" "train/dog.10.jpg" ...

# sample of size 10 from both classes
set.seed(123)
cat_sample <- sample(cats, size = 10, replace = FALSE)
dog_sample <- sample(dogs, size = 10, replace = FALSE)
str(cat_sample); str(dog_sample)
# chr [1:10] "train/cat.12212.jpg" "train/cat.12256.jpg" ...
# chr [1:10] "train/dog.3031.jpg" "train/dog.4819.jpg" "train/dog.7585.jpg" ...

# extract only cat_sample & cat_sample images from train archive
unzip("../input/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip", files = c(cat_sample, dog_sample))
```

Resulting dir tree:

```r
fs::dir_tree()
# .
# └── train
#     ├── cat.11654.jpg
#     ├── cat.12212.jpg
#     ├── cat.12256.jpg
#     ├── cat.1434.jpg
#     ├── cat.1781.jpg
#     ├── cat.6594.jpg
#     ├── cat.7148.jpg
#     ├── cat.8124.jpg
#     ├── cat.9221.jpg
#     ├── cat.9983.jpg
#     ├── dog.12478.jpg
#     ├── dog.1346.jpg
#     ├── dog.3031.jpg
#     ├── dog.3343.jpg
#     ├── dog.430.jpg
#     ├── dog.4819.jpg
#     ├── dog.6979.jpg
#     ├── dog.7035.jpg
#     ├── dog.7585.jpg
#     └── dog.7932.jpg
```

When working on your local system just update the `train.zip` location.